# What is the relationship between $\frac{1}{3}x_1+\frac{1}{3}x_2+\frac{1}{3}x_3$ and $x_1^{\frac{1}{3}}x_2^{\frac{1}{3}}x_3^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Is $\frac{1}{3}x_1+\frac{1}{3}x_2+\frac{1}{3}x_3$ > or < or = $x_1^{\frac{1}{3}}x_2^{\frac{1}{3}}x_3^{\frac{1}{3}}$, given $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are all positive?

I know there exists a real number $a\in(1,2)$ such that $\frac{1}{3}x=x^{\frac {1}{3}}$, but there are three variables even though they are all positive.

Also I know how to simplify $\frac{1}{3}x_1+\frac{1}{3}x_2+\frac{1}{3}x_3-x_1^{\frac{1}{3}}x_2^{\frac{1}{3}}x_3^{\frac{1}{3}}$, but then I get stuck too.

I also tried to relate this to the roots of polynomial, but I don't quite know how.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: This is the $AM \ge GM$ inequality. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$ are positive reals. Furthermore,  
**by [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)**  $\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3} \geq  (x_1)^\frac{1}{3}(x_2)^\frac{1}{3}(x_3)^\frac{1}{3}$

so the proof is using just AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I get what you are saying, but it's best if you include as much details as possible, in case the OP (or other potential readers) doesn't get it.

Comment: sorry so you are asking me to say the generalized proof of that :-) or are you asking me to prove am-gm inequality :-) sorry I didnt get it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can prove this inequality without knowing the more general result: write $x_i=y_i^3$ so$$\frac{y_1^3+y_2^3+y_3^3}{3}-y_1y_2y_3=\tfrac16(y_1+y_2+y_3)((y_1-y_2)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2).$$